# maximum of a function from proportions using optim() in R

Tags: r, proportion

I would like to receive the maximum of a function f(x) where the x are proportions that sum to one.

```
f.max <- function(x){
      x1 <- x[1]      
      x2 <- x[2]
      x3 <- x[3]

      x4 <- 1 - (x1 + x2 + x3)           #(x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) should always be 1     
      d <- (x1*x3 + x1*x4 + x2*x3 + x2*x4)

      x1*4 + x2*6 + x3*3 + x4*2 + d*8    #function to be maximized
      }

optim( par=rep(0.25,3), fn=f.max, gr=NULL, method=c("L-BFGS-B"), lower=rep(0,3), upper=rep(1,3), control=list(fnscale=-1) )
```

While I can constrain the inital values in optim() by the lower= and upper= statement, I do not manage to specify that the maximization is done so that always: (x1 + x2 + x3 + x4) = 1

Answer (score 2):

Do the optimization with respect to the unconstrained parameters
\begin{equation}
\theta_1 = \ln(x_1/x_4), \quad \theta_2=\ln(x_2/x_4), \quad \theta_3=\ln(x_3/x_4).
\end{equation}
The four proportions expressed in terms of $\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ (needed inside your function `f.max`) are then given by
\begin{equation}
x_1=c e^{\theta_1}, \quad x_2=c e^{\theta_2}, \quad x_3=c e^{\theta_3},\quad x_4=c,
\end{equation}
where $c=1/(e^{\theta_1}+e^{\theta_2}+e^{\theta_3}+1)$.